# Problem in Labelling Regex groups in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, data-science, data-cleaning

I have to form a dictionary as {'hostingip' : '146.204.224.152','name' : ricky} from a sentence

**146.204.224.152 - ricky [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 3024622**
Using REGULAR EXPRESSIONS in python.

```
import re
txt = """146.204.224.152 - ricky [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 3024622"""
for x in **re.finditer("^(?P<hostingip>[\d.]+)(?P<name>(?<=-\s)[\w]+)",txt)**:
    print(x.groupdict())
```

The problem is when I try to find the patterns of hosting IP and name separately it is working fine but when I group them together like in the above code, I am not getting any output. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your combined regex pattern must match the entire string.  Consider this working version:

```py
txt = "146.204.224.152 - ricky [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 3024622"
for x in re.finditer("^(?P<hostingip>\d+(?:\.\d+)*) - (?P<name>\w+)", txt):
    print(x.groupdict())
```

This prints:

```
{'hostingip': '146.204.224.152', 'name': 'ricky'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The " - " is static text so just state it as such, don't try to include it in the pattern. So you need some variation on "(pattern1) - (pattern2)"